# Interpreting log transformed linear regression

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, linear, back-transformation

I have created a linear regression model using log transformed data but I'm having issues interpreting the results.

The r^2 of the model is .67 but I'm not sure what else I can report. I guess backtransforming the residual standard error will just bring back the skew. Can I report percentage error in the model?

I also wanted to use prediction intervals but these are only really useful if I backtransform the data so they can be used with the original data. Is this possible?

For example I could then predict a random player's transfer fee using their market value and with 95% confidence say their fee will be between x and y according to my model.

However I'm having trouble even plotting the prediction intervals on the log transformed data. Using the code below I get:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I also get a plot without the prediction intervals.

```
plot(log_mv ~ log_tf, xlab = "Market Value", ylab = "Transfer Fee")
pred_int = predict(log_reg, newdata = data.frame(TransferData), interval="prediction", level = 0.95) #calculate prediction interval
   abline(log_reg, col="red") #regression line
   lines(newdata, pred_int[,2], col="blue", lty=2) #prediction interval lower bound
   lines(newdata, pred_int[,3], col="blue", lty=2) #prediction interval upper bound
legend("bottomright", inset=0.05, bty="n",
   legend = c("Regression Line"),
   lty = c(1),      #1 = solid
   col = c("red")
)
```

[image]

Am I on the right track here?

EDIT: Here is the linear model with the data untransformed.

[image]

And here are the residuals plotted against transfer fees showing increasing errors as fees increase which is why I transformed the data.

[image]

Comment: The heteroscedasticity of the data, together with a regression slope that's reasonably close to $1$, suggest you should revisit the model using the original (untransformed) data. With the transformed data, prediction intervals will be unreliable.

Comment: @whuber I have attached a plot of the model without transforming the data and also plotted residuals against transfer fee.

Comment: The first and the second plots are the same. Could you also attach plots with transformed data?

Comment: @JekaterinaKokatjuhha Apologies. The first plot now shows the transformed data.

Comment: The plots clearly do not show the same data!